# php warning message when leaving an field empty

Tags: php, textbox, warnings, field

I have this code, i want to make a warning message box when people leaves requirement fields empty.

The code:

```
if (@ is_array($cfields)) {
    foreach ($cfields as $cf) {
        if (intval($cf['required']) == 1) {
            if ($cf['type'] == "text" || $cf['type'] == "textarea" || $cf['type'] == "date") {
            ?>
            if(!vrvar.vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>.value.match(/\S/)) {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='#ff0000';
                return false;
            }else {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='';
            }
            <?php

            }elseif ($cf['type'] == "select") {
            ?>
            if(!vrvar.vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>.value.match(/\S/)) {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='#ff0000';
                return false;
            }else {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='';
            }
            <?php

            } elseif ($cf['type'] == "checkbox") {
                //checkbox
            ?>
            if(vrvar.vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>.checked) {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='';
            }else {
                document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='#ff0000';
                return false;
            }
            <?php

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Right now it the text becomes only red when the field is empty.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an **alert** message like this [*see 3rd line*]

```
if(!vrvar.vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>.value.match(/\S/)) {
            document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='#ff0000';
            alert('Please dont leave the field blank');// I have added here
            return false;
            }else {
            document.getElementById('vrcf<?php echo $cf['id']; ?>').style.color='';
            }
```